# Index and Search XML documents

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I want to index and be able to search XML documents using an iPhone/Android app that I am building. I am debating between using ElasticSearch or Google App Engine Search API.

So far I have:

**ElasticSearch**

- will need to convert all XML docs to JSON
- AWS ElasticSearch can provide a hosted solution
- security is an issue as in will need to use EC2 etc. to make sure that only I am able to add content to ElasticSearch and all my app users can only do search queries on elastic search

Overall, seems it will work but will require EC2-ElasticSearch etc. dance.

**Google App Engine**

- quick read of docs not able to figure out how I will be able to index XML/JSON docs
- IF this works then there seems to be considerably lesser work than AWS elasticSearch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Usually discussion based questions don't get a lot of traction. I like elastic search personally,  but I've never used google app engine. To decide, review your data for several more hours and then read the docs of both for about an hour each.

Comment: got it. actually  all I wanted to ask was how google app engine can help because documentation seems woefully inadequate!!!

Answer (score 1):

you do not necessarily need an EC2 instance but can use the [aws elastic search service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) and have a [lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/details/) to convert your documents between xml and JSon

Choosing between AWS and Google (App Engine or Compute Engine) will remain up to you

Comment: Thanks! Understand that lamda is simpler than a full virtual server instance (EC2). Main challenge is can I just use google app engine for all of that for now

Comment: you should probably revised your question and focus on google app engine then and the issue you face with integrating a search engine on it.

Answer (score 0):

I work with both hosted Elastic Search and GAE Search API (go).

I personally would prefer GAE for reasons of simplicity and development speed. Google's cloud also have nice solutions for building mobile backends that are very easily integrated with Search API, eleminating need for administration and security configuration.

ElasticSearch is great choise when you need some specific functions like non-trivial aggregations, advanced statistics etc.

So I would first carefully check requirements if they could be implemented with Search API otherwise use Elastic.